# Test Class of batch Apex which includes a Http Callout in the execute method

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, httpcalloutmock

I'm stuck trying to create a Test class for my batch which execute a Http request. I tried with Test.setMock and also inserted "!Test.isRunningTest()" in the batch but nothing changes. I still have an error when running test.
My question is : How we can use a mock when the callout is part of a batch ?
Here my Batch Apex :

```
global class BatchUpdateGPSLocation implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts{
    
    String googleApiKey = [SELECT xxx, xxxx FROM xxxx].xxxxx__c;
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        
        String query = 'Select Id, Name, Street__c, ZIPCode__c, City__c, Country__c, GPSLocation__Latitude__s, GPSLocation__Longitude__s FROM Opportunity WHERE Country__c !=null AND (GPSLocation__Latitude__s = null OR GPSLocation__Longitude__s = null) LIMIT 10000';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope){
        
        for (Opportunity opp : scope) {
            
            Opportunity oppCountry = [SELECT Id, toLabel(Country__c) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=: opp.Id];
            
            System.debug(opp.Id);
            String address = '';
            if (opp.Street__c != null) {
                address += opp.Street__c+',';
            }
            if (opp.City__c != null) {
                address += opp.City__c+',';
            }
            if (opp.ZIPCode__c != null) {
                address += opp.ZIPCode__c+',';
            }
            
            if (oppCountry.Country__c!= null) {
                address += oppCountry.Country__c;
            }
            
            address = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(address, 'UTF-8');
            System.debug(address);
            String mapUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&key='+googleApiKey+'&sensor=false';
            
            System.debug(mapUrl);
            
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(mapUrl);
            req.setMethod('GET');
            req.setTimeout(10000);
            
            Double lat;
            Double lon;
            try{
                // callout
                HttpResponse res;
                if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                    res = http.send(req);
                }
                system.debug('res.getStatusCode():'+ res.getStatusCode());
                if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    // parse coordinates from response
                    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
                    
                    while (parser.nextToken()!= null) {
                        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'location')){
                            parser.nextToken(); 
                            while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT){
                                String txt = parser.getText();
                                parser.nextToken();
                                if (txt == 'lat')
                                    lat = parser.getDoubleValue();
                                else if (txt == 'lng')
                                    lon = parser.getDoubleValue();
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                // add coordinates in the list
                
                opp.GPSLocation__Latitude__s = lat;
                opp.GPSLocation__longitude__s = lon;
                System.debug('Latitude = '+opp.GPSLocation__Latitude__s);
                System.debug('Longitude = '+opp.GPSLocation__Longitude__s);
                
                oppList.add(opp);
                
                }
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.debug(e.getMessage());
            }
            System.debug('Size of oppList '+oppList.size());
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        
        Database.update(oppList, false); 
    } 
}
```

I have created a Mock class also :

```
global class BatchGPSLocationMock implements HttpCalloutMock{

    global static HttpResponse Respond(HttpRequest request) {
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(); 
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{"results" : [{"address_components" : [{"long_name" : "xxx","short_name" : "xxx","types" : [ "street_number" ]},{"long_name" : "xxxxx","short_name" : "xxxx","types" : [ "route" ]},{"long_name" : "xxx","short_name" : "xxx","types" : [ "locality", "political" ]},{"long_name" : "xxxxxx","short_name" : "xxxxxxx","types" : [ "xx", "political" ]},{"long_name" : "xxxx","short_name" : "xxx","types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]},{"long_name" : "xxxx","short_name" : "xxx","types" : [ "country", "political" ]},{"long_name" : "xxx","short_name" : "xxx","types" : [ "postal_code" ]}],"formatted_address" : "xxxxx, xxxxx, xxxx","geometry" : {"bounds" : {"northeast" : {"lat" : xxxx,"lng" : xxxx},"southwest" : {"lat" : xxxx,"lng" : xxxxxx}},"location" : {"lat" : xxxxxx,"lng" : xxxxxx},"location_type" : "ROOFTOP","viewport" : {"northeast" : {"lat" : xxxxxx,"lng" : xxxxxx},"southwest" : {"lat" : xxxxx,"lng" : xxxx}}},"place_id" : "xxxxxxx","types" : [ "premise" ]}],"status" : "OK"}');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response; 
    }

}
```

And here my class Test in which I tried many things with no success :

```
@isTest
public class BatchUpdateGPSLocationTest {

  @testSetup static void TestData() {
    
      // Create an account
       Account a = TestUtilities.createAccount('KrisKopp');
   
      // Create an opportunity
      Opportunity opp = TestUtilities.initiateOpportunity(a.Id);
      insert opp;
  }

  @isTest static void TestUpdateGPSLocation() {
      
     // Update Adress and set GPS Location as null
      Opportunity oppToUpdate = [SELECT Id, GPSLocation__Latitude__s, GPSLocation__Longitude__s FROM Opportunity];
        oppToUpdate.GPSLocation__Latitude__s = null;
        oppToUpdate.GPSLocation__Longitude__s = null;
      
      update oppToUpdate;
   
    // Assert that Opportunity has no GPS Location
    Opportunity oppChecked = [SELECT Id, GPSLocation__Latitude__s, GPSLocation__Longitude__s FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];
      System.assertEquals(null, oppChecked.GPSLocation__Latitude__s);
      System.assertEquals(null, oppChecked.GPSLocation__Longitude__s);
      
   
      Test.startTest();
      Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new BatchGPSLocationMock());
      BatchUpdateGPSLocation updateGPS = new BatchUpdateGPSLocation();
      Id batchId = database.executeBatch(updateGPS);
      Test.stopTest(); 

    // Assert that the GPS Coordinates have been updated after the batch
    Opportunity oppUpdated = [SELECT Id, GPSLocation__Latitude__s, GPSLocation__Longitude__s FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1];
    System.debug(oppUpdated);
    System.assertEquals(xxxxxx, oppUpdated.GPSLocation__Latitude__s);
    System.assertEquals(xxxxxxx, oppUpdated.GPSLocation__Longitude__s);
    
  }
}
```

Do I need to change my batch by calling another Http Callout Class and this class will be mocked ? But I will loose the possibility to call up to 100 callout, right ?
Can we call separately the start, execute and finish of the batch in the test ?
Thank you for your advises.

Comment: You don't need to call `Database.executeBatch()` in your test. You can use something like `new BatchUpdateGPSLocation().execute(null, new Opportunity[]{oppChecked});`. If you are getting exceptions, I recommend you post those in your question to give better insight so the community can provide clearer assistance.

Comment: Hi, I tried your advice but I have a System Query exception : List has no rows for assignment to SObject.

Comment: Hi, be careful you have a SOQL query inside a loop => poor performance. Also HttpMock and running batch in schedule mode are not compatible in test class. I would advise to put your Http call in a private method with a @testVisible in order to test it separately from the batch execution. In the batch execution, you can make a static mock with Test.isRunningTest() method.